# What common browser plugins should be tested against?

Tags: browsers

In previous companies, I'd decided not to test against Skype plugin breaking my website's UI.

Is it common enough now that it should be tested, just as Flash is/was common place?

I have no analytics on how many users are having the Skype plugin installed which messes with the UI of any telephone numbers.

Having a hard time determining how to justify testing this and if there are other common plugins I should be aware of.

Comment: AdBlock, NoScript, Ghostery...

Comment: @Edu how many people run those ? I think those are more 'techy' rather than something like Skype. Interesting question though, I don't know numbers

Comment: @PhilKirkham Good point. At least for adblock statistics are available at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/statistics/usage/?last=365 and answer seems to be about 15 000 000 daily users.

Answer (score 4):

I believe most computer users in the general population do not install any plugins at all -- especially if you consider mobile users.  Personally, I would not do any plugin compatibility testing  without explicit evidence of a conflict.

By the way, [this](http://blogs.creative-jar.com/post/Stopping-Skype-plugin-replacing-phone-numbers.aspx) recommends a way to prevent the Skype plugin from breaking your page layout.

Answer (score 1):

I have always taken the approach that if people install plug-ins that mess with their UI, they are doing it at their own risk.  It might be a good idea to take a cursory look at your UI while using some of those plug-ins, but I wouldn't spend very much time at all validating or developing around those plug-ins, except for very high severity issues.